# Python: Модуль установлен, но ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, visual-studio, cuda

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку DLIB http://dlib.net/.

Через команду:

> pip install dlib

отлично устанавливается и работает, но как я понял не использует технологию CUDA. Не один день я потратил на эту компиляцию и установку, поэтому покажу последовательность установки, вдруг кто с тем же столкнется:

```
ОС: Windows 7 x64
Python: 2.7.15 x64
Visual Studio 15.8.4 2017
NVidia CUDA 9.2
cudnn-9.2-windows7-x64-v7.2.1.38
```

Когда устанавливал со всеми этими зависимостями, то в лог писалось что версия моей VS не подходит, то до этого где-то вычитал что такое бывает и можно подредактировать чтоб обойти это ограничение.

Поэтому пошел сюда

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include\crt\host_config.h

И на 131 строчки, не помню что там было, что-то типо если версия не ниже и не выше, то сделал не ниже и все, а точнее заменил на эту строку:

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1600
```

Теперь распишу последовательность действий:

```
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="D:/cudnn-9.2-windows7-x64-v7.2.1.38/cuda/"
cmake --build .
```

Здесь все отлично собралось без ошибок, и в логе было видно что CUDA Enabling, в отличие если бы устанавливал по официальной документации.

Далее устанавливаю в Python:

```
cd ..
python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes DLIB_USE_CUDA --set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="D:/cudnn-9.2-windows7-x64-v7.2.1.38/cuda/" --clean
```

После не быстрой и сильно загружающей систему компиляции, было видно что так же CUDA Enabling и в конце зеленым Успешно установлено и библиотека скопирована в директорию:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\dlib-19.15.99-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После не большой радости что наконец-то установил, вылезло вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Я уже и переносил файл dlib.pyd C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\
- Снес и установил все версии Распространяемый пакет Visual C++ для
  Visual Studio, т.к. это где-то писали с аналогичной проблемой, но для
  другой библиотеки.

Нечего не помогло.

Comment: В папке Python есть папка DLLs, где лежат файлы pyd в том числе. Попробуйте положить туда.

Comment: insolor, не помогло

Answer (score 3):

Питон пишет что не найдена библиотека, но это не к dlib относилось, а к требованию какой-то библиотеки прописанной в самом модуле dlib (что я изначально перепутал модуль с библиотекой). И тут меня осенило добавить в переменные среды PATH путь до:

```
D:\cudnn-9.2-windows7-x64-v7.2.1.38\cuda\bin
```

Там и находится требуемая библиотека: cudnn64_7.dll

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]